# How to setup environment variables in Brunch

Tags: node.js, express, brunch, chaplinjs

We're developing an app using Chaplin on top of brunch.

We're consuming a 3rd party API and we have **different tokens for development and production**.

I was wondering if it's possible to setup env variables in Brunch. I'd like to compile everything to plain html/js.

Is there a way to compile the project using something like `brunch build -env staging`? If so, how can I define such variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/332

1) using `brunch cmd --environment ...`

2) using `BRUNCH_ENV=development brunch cmd` + `process.env.BRUNCH_ENV`

Comment: How can I pass a custom environment variable so that it's available to my JavaScript code?